# Double for loop in python

Tags: python-2.7

I try to program now in pythonic. I have next case - some array, which elements I want to iterate with each others... At the moment I coded next example:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

for posx in range(len(a)):
    for posy in range(posx+1, len(a)):
                *some operation for these elements*
```

Now I want to ask some experience Pyhton users, how I can reduce such slow for'loops? Is it possible to use here `zip`tool? How I could understand, `zip` just connect two elements on the same position in two difeerent lists (or arrays). I want to iterate one list over another and get back the operation for every element in both lists.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is available in the standard library as [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
import itertools

for elem1, elem2 in itertools.combinations(a, 2):
    do_whatever_with(elem1, elem2)
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly answer. Accepted